# Синтаксический разбор предложения

Tags: определение

Выделенные слова яв-ся определениями:

```
Дни стоят СИНЕВАТЫЕ, ПАСМУРНЫЕ.
Сегодня утро вышло СЕРОЕ, ТЕПЛОЕ, В ЛУЖАХ.
Небо было ГОРЯЧЕЕ, ВЕТРЕНОЕ, ЯРКОЕ, как синька.
Был ЯРКИЙ МОРОЗНЫЙ ДЕНЬ.
Лес стоит РАДОСТНЫЙ, ПРАЗДНИЧНЫЙ.
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, подробно правильный ответ.

Comment: Вы сами дали ответ на свой вопрос: ''Выделенные слова яв-ся определениями''. Что вас конкретно интересует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Выделенные слова яв-ся
> определениями...

Я вижу только два определения среди выделенных ШРИФТОМ слов: *ЯРКИЙ* и *МОРОЗНЫЙ* (в предложении *"Был ЯРКИЙ МОРОЗНЫЙ день"*).

Все остальные выделенные слова (кроме слова ДЕНЬ) являются **именными частями составных именных сказуемых.**

> Объясните, пожалуйста, подробно
> правильный ответ.

См. http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#31203

Comment: Да. действительно, все выделенные слова являются СИС. Кроме ЯРКИЙ и МОРОЗНЫЙ . 
 Путаница возникает потому, что и именная часть и определение отвечают на один и тот же вопрос: какой. Чтобы не ошибиться, следует обратить внимание от какого слова ставится вопрос какой? к данному имени. Напр.: 
   
 *  > Если вопрос ставится от подлежащего или дополнения, то это определение: У неё было красное (какое?) платье (красное — определение).

  
 * > Если вопрос какой? ставится от глагола, то это именная часть сказуемого: Её платье было (какое?) красное (красное — именная часть сказуемого).

Comment: 

    Если глагола в предложении нет, то надо обратить внимание на порядок слов:

        определение обычно стоит перед подлежащим-существительным: У неё **красное** платье;

        именная часть сказуемого обычно стоит после подлежащего-существительного: Её платье **красное**.

Answer (score 3):

*Дни* - подлежащее. Что о них говорится? - что они стоят СИНЕВАТЫЕ, ПАСМУРНЫЕ. - составные именные сказуемые. Важно не то, что они стоят, а то, что они синеватые и пасмурные.

Сегодня утро вышло СЕРОЕ, ТЕПЛОЕ, В ЛУЖАХ. - составные именные сказуемые с глаголом-связкой ВЫШЛО. Что говорится об утре? - что оно вышло (т.е. получилось) серое, тёплое, в лужах.

Небо было ГОРЯЧЕЕ, ВЕТРЕНОЕ, ЯРКОЕ, как синька. - составные именные сказуемые.

Был ЯРКИЙ МОРОЗНЫЙ день. День что делал? - был. День какой? - яркий, морозный - определения.

Лес стоит РАДОСТНЫЙ, ПРАЗДНИЧНЫЙ. - составные именные сказуемые. Важно не то, что он стоит, а то, что он радостный и праздничный. А вот если бы было: Стоит радостный, праздничный лес - это были бы определения.